# How to put the problem of html code in database

Tags: python, html, django, database, dynamic

I was trying to include a hyperlink between the text which loads dynamically from database, similar to the one in wikipedia. 
The text somehow looks like this -

```
"Some Text some text <a href="#">Hyperlink</a>Remaining text"
```

But is doesn't gives me a hyperlink, instead it shows the same text as i have written in the database. When i checked the source code it look like this:

```
"Some Text &lt;a href="#"&gt;Hyperlink&lt;/a&gt; Remaining Text"
```

I expect the ouput as as -
"Some Text Hyperlink Remaining Text"

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Show your template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render it with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) to mark it as safe, and thus prevent the template engine from HTML escaping it.

```
{{ myvariable|safe }}
```

If `myvariable` thus is a string `'"Some Text some text <a href="#">Hyperlink</a>Remaining text"'`, it will be rendered as `"Some Text some text <a href="#">Hyperlink</a>Remaining text"`.